# No server in windows>preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I'm trying to add Apache server to Eclipse(Juno). I have installed Apache server 7.0, but when I try to add this to the Eclipse environment I don't see the options server in **windows>preferences**. There must be an option called server in preferences to add Tomcat server.

Please, help me on how to get that option?

Do I need to install any plugin? If yes, please, provide me the link or the name.

Comment: try posting on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You did not install the correct Eclipse distribution. Try install the one labeled "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers".

Comment: yes thanks i have installed IDE for java EE and its working now

Answer (score 53):

In Eclipse Kepler,

1. go to Help, select ‘Install New Software’
2. Choose “Kepler- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler” site or add it in if it’s missing.
3. Expand “Web, XML, and Java EE Development” section Check `JST Server Adapters` and `JST Server Adapters Extensions` and install it

After Eclipse restart, go to Window / Preferences / Server / Runtime Environments

Comment: Select the ones you need otherwise it will take too long to finish installation.

Comment: The same works for Eclipse Mars (changing the link accordingly to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. I was using eclipse platform and server was missing in my show view. To fix this go:

- help>install new software
- in  work with : select : "Indigo Update Site - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/" , once selected, all available software will be displayed in the section under type filter text
- Expand “Web, XML, and Java EE Development” and select "JST Server adapters  extensions"
- then click next and finish.
  The server should be displayed in show view

Answer (score 4):

You can also install the required packages with Help -> Install new software...

See http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php for the packages you need to install to have eclipse IDE for java EE developers

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

```
1.Goto Help -> Install new Software
2.Give address http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen and name as your choice.
3.Search for Java EE and choose 1.Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 
4.Search for JST and choose 2.JST Server Adapters 3.JST Server Adapters 
5.Click next and accept the license agreement.
```

Find the server option in the window-->preferences and add server as you need

Comment: Additional information- For Apache Tomcat Server, you will have to include **JST Server Adapter Extensions** as well.

Answer (score 0):

If above answers did not work for you then just click this link https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers download according to your OS. And after downloading and extracting the ZIP open the extract folder and click on Eclipse application icon.
[image]

Then just enter your workspace and get started. Now you will be able to see the servers option in Window->Show View, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Help
2. Eclipse Marketplace
3. In the find option, search for ***JST server adapter*** and then install