# Eclipse - no Server view

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have installed a Eclipse Kepler and am trying to configure it to use Tomcat. However, there is no "Server View" under "Window>Preferences". I have tried "Window > Show View > Other..." and then type Servers in the filter, but it does not show up? Do I need to install a plugin?

Comment: Did you try this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317854/no-server-in-windowspreferences

Comment: You need the JEE version of Eclipse for that OR you could install all the plugins manually (I won't recommend that since eclipse does have a habit of messing up if you are not careful what plugin you download and install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by installing Eclipse-JEE. It recognised the Eclipse I had already installed, and spent a lot of time on configuring, and configured its self for me. I was very re-leaved as I expected to spend hours re-doing all the work. So if you have a similar issue do not hesitate to install Eclipse-JEE (do not remove the old Eclipse first).

Regards,

Glyn